# Android async task - no activity found to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm using async task to create loading screen, but when I want to pass intent to main activity, app crash... here's some code:

```
 public class StartActivity extends Activity {
     protected boolean _active = true;
     protected int _splashTime = 5000;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited <_splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited +=100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
            } finally {

                startActivity(new Intent("HNappActivity"));
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
    }
```

here's manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hnapp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="HNappActivity"></activity>
```

logcat:

```
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=HNappActivity }
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
  09-24 20:47:06.841: E/AndroidRuntime(556):    at sk.ecopress.hn.android.StartActivity$1.run(StartActivity.java:37)
```

StartActivity class is started first, it shows loading screen and then it should pass intent to main activity, but it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
    startActivity(new Intent("HNappActivity"));
```

to:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, HNappActivity.class));
```

Also that activity must exist in your project which I'm assuming it does.

Comment: oh, I forgot about that... thanks.. and please, when main activity starts, there is like 5 sec black screen, while logcat is spreading messages about garbace collector and after 5 secs, layout is loaded. Can main's activity layout be loaded while startactivity is resumed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. With the code you posted you will see whatever is in R.layout.loading_screen for 5 seconds before moving on to the HNappActivity.

Comment: yes, and during those 5 seconds, I want to load HNappActivity, and show it imidiately after those 5 seconds. because now, 5 second pass, then it takes 3-4 seconds to load HNappActivity and after those 3-4 seconds, activity is shown. so I want to change that. any idea?

Comment: Well the code above waits 5 seconds before loading the next activity. Why not lose the thread sleep altogether and just launch the next activity instantly? Also if it takes 3 to 4 seconds to load your next activity you might want to look at optimizing how you are loading the next activity.

Comment: the point was fill those 3-4 seconds with some image, so screen wont be black. and i really dont know why it is launching so long, logcat is spreading just some garbage collector messages ..

Comment: Is the loading_screen.xml filled with an image? It should show the contents of loading_screen.xml. Given the UI might be frozen while the new activity loads.

Comment: well, not yet. thats not the point. point is to load new activity in background and show it when it is fully loaded. and in the meantime loading_screen.xml is shown

Comment: Put an image in the loading_screen.xml and see if you see it. With the code above you should see the image if you have one set in the XML.

Comment: i can see the image, but the next activity starts to load just after the image dissapear. thats the problem. so there is 4 seconds of black page

Comment: You could try setting the theme of HNappActivity in the manifest to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent". This might solve the issue but I think you might want to refactor the code in HNappActivity. I would suggest removing StartActivity altogether and in HNappActivity you should first just show a loading view and perform the long loading in a background thread. Once the loading is finished you can make a call to setContentView again and it will replace the loading layout with the new one. This will give you more control on how the loading of HNappActivity will effect the UI.

Comment: wow, can you show me code how to call setContentView in a background thread?

Comment: You cannot call setContentView in a background thread because it will modify the UI. You would have to load any resources such as images or other need content in the background and pass it back to the main thread to actually display this on screen. You should look into AsyncTask, this allows for very easy background loading. I think this should posted as a new question and include the onCreate of the HNappActivity.

Comment: You should create a new question and post the code. There is no reason an activity like that should take more than half a second to load. You can link to the new question in the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
<activity android:name="HNappActivity"></activity>
```

to

```
 <activity android:name=".HNappActivity"></activity>
```

the dot before the class name matter.

and as they said, you must call activity using

```
  startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, HNappActivity.class));
```